# Mage registry key "_singleton/Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy" already exists

Tags: magento

I'm running into a problem on our backend part of Magento (/admin). It throws up an error:

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy" already exists
```

It creates a report with the following content:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:74:"Mage registry key "_singleton/Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy" already exists";i:1;s:1693:"#0 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php(224): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')

1 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php(478): Mage::register('_singleton/Mage...', false)

2 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Core_Model...')

3 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php(449): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)

4 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(528): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)

5 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()

6 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()

7 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')

8 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

9 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

10 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php(685): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

11 /home/kfrijters/domains/wijnmaat.nl/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: clear var/cache data and try again.

Comment: Thanks Gulshan. We already tried that but without any luck. Do you have another solution?

Comment: @BrentStevens, did you found the solution for this.? Can you post it as answer